# ServiceStack google OpenID suddenly not logging in

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dns, servicestack

Got a site still in dev that uses ServiceStack's Open ID implementation to sign in users. It's been working fine all this time, suddenly today morning Google's OpenID login started failing, Facebook still authenticates fine. No error is thrown, just redirects back to the default url with this appended to it:

```
#f=Unknown
```

On my localhost it works flawlessly, both Google and FB login ok, only in production does it fail. I have tried quite a lot:

1. Re-verified each and every file in my asp.net bin folder compared with local and production, no difference.
2. Re-routed the production domain name to my localhost (in the hosts file), in hopes to step through the creation of the session. No luck, still signs in flawlessly.
3. Connected via remote desktop to the server and tried logging in on it as localhost, fails. (yea, WTH?).

Is there a way I can get a log of what is going on as the authentication is happening? or does anyone have an idea of what could be the issue?

On a side note: I recently changed dns settings for the domain name and moved it to this new server, but that was around 3-4 days ago, and it's been working fine all this time, until today morning. Also noticed that a reverse DNS lookup on my IP resolves to a different domain, investigating that right now.

**UPDATE**

This issue reared it's ugly head again this morning. I'm not sure what could be causing it but I suspect windows automatic time synchronization to be somehow throwing things off. I'm turning it off and going to keep an eye on things to see if it returns. Also, this issue seems to throw my SSL settings into chaos, i have to manually reset IIS's SSL bindings in order for things to work, even WebDeply is affected. Very strange.

**UPDATE 2**
Issue happened again today. I'm now suspecting it's somehow related to IIS's web deploy feature cause it happened immediately after I published my site.  Also now realised that I don't need to reboot, a simple iisreset seems to fix it. Will keep monitoring.

**FINAL UPDATE**
I finally found the culprit. Time. My virtual server was gaining time very fast and every few days it would be ahead of most other servers and so the authentication would fail. The limit seemed to be around 3-5minutes, within that range, the authentication works okay. More than that, it fails. To get around it, simply enable time syncing and it should not re-appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your production server clock. The OpenID request synch with the internet time in order to validate the request. If the clock is off or it was off for a while just reboot and the problem will be solved.

Comment: After all the years I've been coding I'm still baffled at how a simple reboot fixes things. Thanks for your suggestion, a reboot sorted it out.